# Apache nifi localhost login problem - cannot see login GUI after using for the first time

Tags: apache-nifi

Problem:

I'm using apache nifi on ubuntu 18.04 on virtualbox 6.1. I manage to use apache nifi once without any problems. The log in page using localhost:8443 works the first time, but after a while when I start apache nifi again (e.g. after a reboot of the machine) and when I goto localhost:8443 again I do not get a page to log into nifi anymore.

All that appears are some symbols and I cannot log into nifi like the first time. Basically I want to be able to log into apache nifi. I'm not sure why the symbols appear instead of the log in page.

[image: nifi login image]

Here's what I do:

I start apache nifi-1.16.3 from its installation with its start command:

```
bin/nifi.sh start
bin/nifi.sh status
```

Nifi looks to start correctly and the status command shows that nifi is running

[image: nifi start and status]

I then enter `localhost:8443/nifi/login` in firefox web browser and I am presented a page that only contains symbols.

What i've tried:

I've downloaded nifi again and started another instance using the fresh download. This does the same i.e. it will show the login page correctly the first time I use it. Then when I try to access the login page after a time via the localhost it will show the symbols instead of the log in page.

I've checked to see whether the port 8443 is being used by something else but it seems free. When nifi is running I check the port, then I shut it down. Once it is shut down no other service etc. is using port 8443. When trying to access localhost:8443 instead of the symbols it shows "Unable to connect" when nifi is shutdown down.

[image]

Not sure what else to explore to solve this issue where I can't access the log in GUI through the localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a secure HTTP protocol like this: [Local Host](https://localhost:8443/nifi/login)

[image: ScreenShot]